# Share data between method in serializer (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have quite heavy calculation and a lot of database access but reusable in SerializerMethodField of ModelSerializer, how should I result that calculated data across the method.

Example Code

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    b = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_a(self, obj):
        result_x = heavy_calculation(self.context['request'].user, obj)
        return result_x + 1

    def get_b(self, obj):
        result_x = heavy_calculation(self.context['request'].user, obj)
        return result_x + 2
```

heavy_calculation() in both method is the same function so result_x would be the same answer for any requests. I would like to make heavy_calculation() call only once per requests to reduce load work (my real work would like to call 10+ times)

Best Regards,

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Your process seems okay.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I edit question with more detail, thank

Answer (score 2):

There're few options for your case:

- If you could rewrite your serializer class:

```
    class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        a = serializers.IntegerField()

        def calc_a(self, obj):
            return self._cached_result + 1

        def to_representation(self, instance):
            data = super().to_representation(instance)
            self._cached_result = heavy_calculation(self.context['request'].user, instance)
            data['a'] = self.calc_a(instance)
            ...
            return data
```

- Using python3 LRU cache (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

```
@lru_cache
def heavy_calculation(user, obj):
   ...
```

- There're [django-memoize](https://pypi.org/project/django-memoize/) libary that cache your function result (you'll need to setup cache for your Django site)

```
@memoize(timeout=60)
def heavy_calculation(user, obj):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.
1. You can override **init** and populate data with object_id and result in a dictionary.
2. You can write list serializer and override data property and populate on your own. Guide of writing list serializer [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer)

Comment: I don't think overriding `__init__` would work when serializing a list of objects.